# Pygame: Use an image for the background of a menu

Tags: python, pygame

I am relatively new to Pygame and struggling to find a way to make a menu. Here is the main menu that I designed. -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx9Sw.jpg)

I want for the player to be able to click each of the 6 buttons which will take them to their different menus. Currently all I am able to do is blit the image to the screen in a while true loop as well as pygame.display.flip but cannot interact with it in anyway.

What is the best way going about this? Are there any tutorials out there for this kind of menu that you have used as I cannot find one personally.

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has no GUI elements so you have to do on your own.

You can keep "button" rectangle (positon and size) as `pygame.Rect()` , and use mouse event to get mouse position when you click. Then you can use pygame "collision detection" functions to check if mouse position collides with button rectangle.

See [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) functions.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I gave it a go to make a rectangle around the Single Player using get mouse position to get the co-ordinates. This gave the following error however:  "SinglePlayer = pygame.rect(((42,515),(310,487)), (546, 55))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" has something been done wrong here? Pygame has been fully imported.

Comment: read doc carefully. `Rect()` not `rect()`. and `Rect` expects four integer numbers - x, y, width, height - you have six numbers. Use `single_player = pygame.Rect(x, y, width,height)` to create rectangle. Then you can move it using `single_player.x = new_x` and `single_player.y = new_y` anc check collision with mouse `if single_player.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):`

Comment: there is document `PEP8` with suggestions how to name variables in Python, etc. It suggests to use `lower_case` names for variables, objects, instances, functions and `CamelCase` names for classes